# Calculating distance between multiple geopositions in Java

Tags: java, android, eclipse, geolocation, distance

I was wondering how to correctly use the Location.distanceBetween method in Java to get the distance through multiple points.

Say you have a latitudeList and longitudeList, and you'd use a for=loop through them, how to use that method (effectively)?
I seem to get the wrong distance value.

The code I'm using currently (it's messy but it seemed allright):

```
float result = 0;
float[] resultList = new float[1];
for (int k = 0; k < latitudeList.size() - 1; k++)
{
    Location.distanceBetween(latitudeList.get(k), longitudeList.get(k), latitudeList.get(k+1), longitudeList.get(k + 1), resultList);                        
    result = result + resultList[0];
    resultList = new float[1];
}
```

What did I do wrong?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You seem to use ``resultaat[0]`` as result value while distanceBetween(..) method returns it in ``resultList[0]``. Also there's no need to create new ``resultList`` on every iteration.

Comment: Sorry, I typo'd. I changed the names to english for this post so users here can understand what I actually did... So, the question remains :/

Comment: What makes you think that the result is incorrect?

Comment: I can draw a route through Google Maps using touches (draws lines), and the calculation of the round starts when it crosses an other line. When I 'walk' around my houseblock, i get a value between 2 and 3. If I walk to the next town and back, I get something like 4 or 5. I once made a giant trip and got around 1,5. So, I hoped someone here could spot an error in my use of `distanceBetween`, but I'm afraid it's somewhere else in my code :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why are you doing???

```
result = result+resultat[0] ???
```

while your distance is in resultList[0].

modify your code like this

```
float result = 0;
float[] resultList = new float[1];
for (int k = 0; k < latitudeList.size() - 1; k++)
{
    Location.distanceBetween(latitudeList.get(k), longitudeList.get(k),           latitudeList.get(k+1), longitudeList.get(k + 1), resultList);                        
    result = result + resultList[0];

}
```

Comment: I think the poster also needs to either change the `<` to `<=` or iterate all the way to `size()` rather than `size()-1`.

Comment: No, he has n = latitudeList.size() points but only n-1 distances between them. The greatest k is n-2, thus k+1 in the last iteration references point n-2+1, i.e. point n-1. This is correct, since indexing in the list is 0-based.

Comment: I'm sorry, it was a typo. It actually says `result = result + resultList[0];` :(

Comment: The error seemed to be in the code around it. I'll accept this answer since the answer is correct in its own way. Thanks all :)